# Can i block insert into all table using a server trigger for a specified database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can i block insert into all table using a server trigger for a specified database

Comment: Too vague, no explanation of why you need A) a trigger and b) current roles, procedures are insufficient to manage what if any is inserted into a theoretical table.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to prevent records being inserted in any table by writing a server trigger then the answer is no that's not possible.

The server triggers only handles DDL (CREATE, ALTER, DROP...) and not DML (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Server triggers:

```
-- Trigger on a CREATE, ALTER, DROP, GRANT, DENY, REVOKE,  
--  or UPDATE STATISTICS statement (DDL Trigger)  

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name   
ON { ALL SERVER | DATABASE }   
[ WITH <ddl_trigger_option> [ ,...n ] ]  
{ FOR | AFTER } { event_type | event_group } [ ,...n ]  
AS { sql_statement  [ ; ] [ ,...n ] | EXTERNAL NAME < method specifier >  [ ; ] }  

<ddl_trigger_option> ::=  
    [ ENCRYPTION ]  
    [ EXECUTE AS Clause ]  



-- Trigger on a LOGON event (Logon Trigger)  

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name   
ON ALL SERVER   
[ WITH <logon_trigger_option> [ ,...n ] ]  
{ FOR| AFTER } LOGON    
AS { sql_statement  [ ; ] [ ,...n ] | EXTERNAL NAME < method specifier >  [ ; ] }  

<logon_trigger_option> ::=  
    [ ENCRYPTION ]  
    [ EXECUTE AS Clause ]
```

Comment: You would need a trigger on each table